# How often do funding agencies require funded authors to publish their work in open access venues?

Tags: funding, reference-request, open-access

Some funding agencies [such as the Gates Foundation require funded authors to publish their work in open access venues](http://www.nature.com/news/gates-foundation-research-can-t-be-published-in-top-journals-1.21299).

Is there any research/study/survey that tried to quantify the percentage of funding agencies that require funded authors to publish their work in open access venues.

I am interested in any data that could share some light on that question, e.g. historical trends or weighting by funding agency size.

---

For example, 
The RoMEO Journals database contains thousands of journals, labeled with their archiving policy ([preprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preprint)/[postprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postprint)/publisher's version):

[image]

One could imagine a similar database for funding agencies with paper  access policies.

Answer (score 3):

SHERPA, which produces RoMEO, also produces a database on funders' open access policies, called [SHERPA/JULIET](http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/juliet/index.php). There is a statistics page on the JULIET website.

According to this page, 26% of funders worldwide require publication in an open access venue, 30% encourage this, and 41% have no policy.

When it comes to archiving the publication in an open access repository, 68% of funders require this, 12% encourage, and 17% have no policy.